# Keeping 2D interpolation within shape

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have a collection of measuring points and I want to interpolate between them, for which I use SciPy's griddata():

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from scipy.interpolate import griddata 

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0.1, 0.9, 2, 3.05, 4, 0, 1, 2.2, 3, 3.95], 
    'force': [1, 2, 4, 9, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -4, -9, -16]
})

Times, Forces = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(0, 4, 100),
    np.linspace(-16, 16, 100)
)

data['work'] = data['time'] * data['force']

interpolation = griddata(
    (data['time'], data['force']), 
    data['work'], 
    (Times, Forces), 
    method= 'linear'
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 

contour = ax.contourf(
    Times, Forces, interpolation
)
ax.scatter(data['time'], data['force'])

fig.show()
```

My problem is, that my measuring points already follow the borders of the physical possibilities, but the interpolation will nontheless interpolate for every spannable area, including those which aren't reachable to measure.

How can I limit the interpolation or at least the plot of the interpolation to 'within' the shape of the outer points? Unfortunately the 'time' measurement has small deviations.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `ax.tricontourf(data['time'], data['force'], data['work'],...)`? This would use a triangulation of the convex hull of the given coordinates.

Comment: @JohanC I hadn't, but it suffers from the same problem I'm afraid. But I'll probably use it anyhow, as it is a more elegant version of what I'm soing so far, so definitely thanks for that! :) 
But maybe I could create a mask that could cover the out of bound areas...

Comment: Probably it'll work adding points in the out of bounds region with `work` value `np.nan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to get the concave polygon for all the points. Secondly, Using the polygon to clip the contour fill. Although, this may be a bit complicated, some useful packages can help these tasks.

Below is the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.path as mpath

import alphashape
from descartes import PolygonPatch

Path = mpath.Path

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0.1, 0.9, 2, 3.05, 4, 0, 1, 2.2, 3, 3.95],
    'force': [1, 2, 4, 9, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -4, -9, -16]
})

Times, Forces = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(0, 4, 100),
    np.linspace(-16, 16, 100)
)

data['work'] = data['time'] * data['force']

interpolation = griddata(
    (data['time'], data['force']),
    data['work'],
    (Times, Forces),
    method= 'linear')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xlim(-.3,4.3)
plt.ylim(-18,18)

#contour = ax.contourf( Times, Forces, interpolation)
contour = ax.tricontourf( data['time'], data['force'], data['work'])
ax.scatter(data['time'], data['force'])


x = data['time']
y =  data['force']

points = np.vstack([x, y]).T
alpha = 0.95 * alphashape.optimizealpha(points)
hull = alphashape.alphashape(points, alpha)
hull_pts = hull.exterior.coords.xy

ax.scatter(hull_pts[0], hull_pts[1], color='red')
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(hull, fill=False, color='red'))

plt.savefig("clip_before.png")
#make clip path
vertices = []
codes = []
xpts,ypts = hull_pts

## convert polygon to path for cliping contour fill
for ix,iy in zip(xpts,ypts):
    vertices.append((ix,iy))
codes += [Path.MOVETO]
codes += [Path.LINETO] * (len(xpts) -2)
codes += [Path.CLOSEPOLY]
clip = Path(vertices, codes)

for collection in contour.collections:
    collection.set_clip_path(clip,transform=ax.transData)
plt.savefig("clip_after.png")
plt.show()
```

And here is the output figures.

Befor clipping.
[image: before clip]

After clipping.

[image: after clip]

Comment: That is really elegant, thank you very much! One question though: The shape of the created polygon is influenced by alpha right? Why 0.95 and can the polygon also be defined to go through more points?